# CakePHP 2.2 auth component

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

Hi I am very new to CakePHP, I wrote a basic login page using cakephp2.2.

This is my `AppController`:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    var $components = array('Auth', 'Session');
    var $helpers = array('Form');
    public function appError($error) {
        //Do whatever you want
        debug($error);
    }

}
```

My UsersController:app\controller\UsersController.php

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Users';
    var $components = array('Auth'); // Not necessary if declared in your app controller
    /**
    * The AuthComponent provides the needed functionality
    * for login, so you can leave this function blank.
    */
    function login() {
    }
    function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
}
```

And my view:app\user\login.ctp

```
<?php
echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

I am getting: the hole UserController code and below error

\app\Controller\AppController.php (line 41)
object(MissingControllerException) {

}

Comment: Check your error log: **/app/tmp/logs/error.log**

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to class declarations for the AppController, or is it a copy/paste mistake?

```
<?php
  class AppController extends Controller {
    class AppController extends Controller {
    }
  }
?>
```

If so, you should remove the second `class AppController extends Controller` statement.

Also, you haven't included the `FormHelper` in either your `AppController` nor `UsersController`.

```
<?php
  class AppController extends Controller {
    var $helpers = array('Form');
  }
?>
```

Including it in the `AppController`will make it available in your entire Cake app, or you could just make it available to the `UsersController` by adding it there.

**EDIT:**
Your problem is in [the routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) part of the application. A default install of Cake has some routes set up in `/app/Config/routes.php`. This is an important line:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
```

It connects a method of the default `PagesController` (which is a standard controller included in every Cake install) to the home view. You've probably removed the  `PagesController`, which is throwing an error. You can recreate the `PagesController` (e.g. by downloading it), or you can update your routes to redirect users directly to the login screen when they visit your application:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'home'));
```

Comment: sorry that was really a copy paste mistake. i have added FormHelper in AppController but still same error.

Comment: What's the filename of your view? Does it have a `.ctp` extension.

Comment: its login.ctp and path:"app\view\user\login.ctp"

Comment: now i find a Fatal error: Class 'View' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\cake262\lib\Cake\Controller\Controller.php on line 941

Comment: i modified my appcontroller as `class AppController extends Controller {

 var $components = array('Auth', 'Session');
    var $helpers = array('Form');

  public function appError($error) {
        //Do whatever you want
        debug($error);
  }
      
    
   
}` it displays in browser `class UsersController extends AppController { var $name = 'Users'; var $components = array('Auth'); function login() { } function logout() { $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout()); } }
\app\Controller\AppController.php (line 41)
object(MissingControllerException) {
 
}   i mean it points to debug($error);
`

Comment: Could you update your question with the code above, it's very hard to read without proper formatting.

Comment: Because you've overridden `appError()` in the AppController the app is giving very limited debugging information, normally Cake is much more verbose (especially when it comes to missing controllers, views or actions). In any case you're missing a required controller, when your temporarily remove `appError()` from the `AppController` you can probably see which controller is missing exactly.

Comment: i removed appError() in AppController i am getting Fatal error: Class 'View' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\cake262\lib\Cake\Controller\Controller.php on line 941

Comment: i checked error logs it says [MissingControllerException] Controller class UsersController could not be found.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: i have the PagesController but still i changed the router and checked no use same error. i am using cakephp2.2 and i heard that there is a difference in usage of auth component in cake2.2...?

Comment: Remove the `appError()` from your AppController, it's interfering with debugging at the moment. Then ascertain which controller is missing. I've just recreated your setup in a fresh install of Cake and it's working fine.

Comment: i removed appError() from AppController. it shows UsersController not found. my table name is Users in database is that ok i checked the UserController code its fine i dont know why it shows UserController is missing.

Comment: You've named the Controller `UserController` and Cake is asking for a `UsersController`. Also, are the directories capitalised (so "Controller", instead of "controller"), not sure if this will have any effect, though.